# Passing column/variable as binary value to convert function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, varbinary

I am manipulating a large value containing rows and columns values separated with ASCII row and column separators. The result is tabular data which I am inserting in SQL table.

Simple example to get the idea:

```
George|20;Ivan|15;Peter|10;
```

is transform to:

```
George 20
Ivan   15
Peter  10
```

and inserted in `Users ([name], [age]`) table.

Before insert, each value is converted to its column type using `TRY_CONVERT` function. The issue is this does not work as expected with `VARBINARY` data. For example (the second output is correct):

```
DECLARE @A NVARCHAR(1024) = '0xFE520676B1A1D93DABAB2319EEA03674F3632EAEEB163D1E88244F5EB1DE10EB';

SELECT TRY_CONVERT(VARBINARY(255), @A) 
-- 0x300078004600450035003200300036003700360042003100410031004400390033004400410042004100420032003300310039004500450041003000330036003700340046003300360033003200450041004500450042003100360033004400310045003800380032003400340046003500450042003100440045003100300045004200

SELECT TRY_CONVERT(VARBINARY(255), 0xFE520676B1A1D93DABAB2319EEA03674F3632EAEEB163D1E88244F5EB1DE10EB)   
-- 0xFE520676B1A1D93DABAB2319EEA03674F3632EAEEB163D1E88244F5EB1DE10EB
```

When the `VARBINARY` data is passed as string, the string is converting itself to `VARBINARY`. I need to pass the data without quotes, but how to do this when a column/variable of type string is passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use the `style` option of the [TRY_CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) function.

```
DECLARE @A NVARCHAR(1024) = '0xFE520676B1A1D93DABAB2319EEA03674F3632EAEEB163D1E88244F5EB1DE10EB';

-- using style option 1
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(VARBINARY(255), @A, 1) 
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(VARBINARY(255), 0xFE520676B1A1D93DABAB2319EEA03674F3632EAEEB163D1E88244F5EB1DE10EB)
```

Comment: You found and post the answer few seconds earlier :) I will delete my answer, take upvote!